# List iteration value (int) doesn't match Pandas cell value, but should?

Tags: python, pandas

Looping through a list of integers should match integers in a Pandas Dataframe cell, yet it does not - even when converting values to the same datatypes (eg. np.int64, int, string).

```
business_cards = [1111,2222]
for i in business_cards:
     purchases['Card_Class'] = ['Business' if x == int(i) else 0 for x in purchases['CC']]
```

Above doesn't work. But this does work:

```
business_cards = [1111,2222]
for i in business_cards:
     purchases['Card_Class'] = ['Business' if x == 1111 else 0 for x in purchases['CC']]
```

I have this nagging sense I've missed something basic, but am totally stuck.

Comment: Same problem if I use: `purchases['Card_Class'] = np.where(purchases['CC'] == str(i), 'Business', ' ')`

Comment: Could you share more of your program, and about what you’re trying to do? Explicit loops should be avoided in Pandas. What do the numbers 1111 and 2222 denote? Are they some kind of ID, a category, ...?

Answer (score 1):

If the only two business card types are 1111 & 2222 something like this would work as a *quick fix*:

`purchases['Card_Class'] = 1*(purchases['CC']==1111) + 1*(purchases['CC']==2222)`

However, for a more *general* approach (allowing for more business_card types) you can use the following:

```
business_cards = [1111,2222]
ind = pd.get_dummies(purchases['CC'])
purchases['Card_Class'] = ind[business_cards].sum(axis=1)
```

Lastly if it is important that your column is a binary indicator 'Business' or 0 (as indicated in your initial code). You can replace 1's with 'Business':

```
df['Card_Class'] = df['Card_Class'].replace(1,'Business')
```